# Calculation output not transfering

Tags: c#, visual-studio, simple-form

I'm trying to add multiple user inputbox inputs together do calculations then display them into label boxes. I can't figure out why when I use the calculate btn. My label box's just equal 0. My btnClear works to clear the input textbox's too. If I change miscChargelbl.Text = miscCharge.ToString();     to miscChargelbl.Text = 1.ToString(); it displays the misc charge label box as 1. But if I leave it as before it puts 0, meaning it isn't taking the calculation from CalcMiscCharges(). How would I get this to output the correct text into the empty label.

```
    //*Variables*//
    private double dayCharge;
    private double mediCharge;
    private double surgCharge;
    private double labCharge;
    private double rehabCharge;
    private double daysStay;
    private double stayCharge;
    private double miscCharge;
    private double totalCharge;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /*I Cant figure why this doesn't change the labels to the inputted text*/
        miscChargelbl.Text = miscCharge.ToString();
        stayChargelbl.Text = stayCharge.ToString();
        totalChargelbl.Text = totalCharge.ToString();
        
    }
    private void CalcStayCharges()
    {
        /*Calculate the days stayed price*/
        dayCharge = 350;
        daysStay = Double.Parse(daySpenttxt.Text);
        stayCharge = dayCharge * daysStay;
       
        
    }
    private void CalcMiscCharges() 
    {
        mediCharge = double.Parse(medicationtxt.Text);
        surgCharge = double.Parse(surgicaltxt.Text);
        labCharge = double.Parse(labfeetxt.Text);
        rehabCharge = double.Parse(rehabtxt.Text);

        miscCharge = mediCharge + surgCharge + labCharge + rehabCharge;
        
    }
    private void CalcTotalCharges()
    {
        /*Add stay charge with misc charge*/
        totalCharge = stayCharge + miscCharge;
    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        /*Clears and resets textboxes for new data */
        medicationtxt.Text = String.Empty;
        surgicaltxt.Text = String.Empty;
        labfeetxt.Text = String.Empty;
        rehabtxt.Text = String.Empty;
        daySpenttxt.Text = String.Empty;
    }
}
```

}
'''

Comment: Why should it take the result from CalcMiscCharges? Probably you would want to move that code into CalcMiscCharges and call CalcMiscCharges() in click. Reading again. your calculations are scattered unnecessarily. They need to be called all.

Comment: Where do you actually invoke `CalcStayCharges()`? I suspect you might not be calling the method before changing the label text. Do you call this method somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

(Would be a mess for a comment)

I would recommend you to read Binding and use Binding instead.For the time being(likely a hobby project), try changing the code like this:

```
//*Variables*//
private decimal dayCharge;
private decimal mediCharge; // change the rest to decimal also
                            // ...

private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Calculate();
}

private void Calculate()
{
    /* Use TryParse instead of Parse */
    
    /*Calculate the days stayed price*/
    dayCharge = 350;
    daysStay = decimal.Parse(daySpenttxt.Text);
    stayCharge = dayCharge * daysStay;

    mediCharge = decimal.Parse(medicationtxt.Text);
    surgCharge = decimal.Parse(surgicaltxt.Text);
    labCharge = decimal.Parse(labfeetxt.Text);
    rehabCharge = decimal.Parse(rehabtxt.Text);

    miscCharge = mediCharge + surgCharge + labCharge + rehabCharge;

    /*Add stay charge with misc charge*/
    totalCharge = stayCharge + miscCharge;

    /*I Cant figure why this doesn't change the labels to the inputted text*/
    miscChargelbl.Text = miscCharge.ToString();
    stayChargelbl.Text = stayCharge.ToString();
    totalChargelbl.Text = totalCharge.ToString();
}

private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    /*Clears and resets textboxes for new data */
    medicationtxt.Text = String.Empty;
    surgicaltxt.Text = String.Empty;
    labfeetxt.Text = String.Empty;
    rehabtxt.Text = String.Empty;
    daySpenttxt.Text = String.Empty;
}
```

PS: Also note that none of those variables need to declared. They are all used in Calculate and would simply be local variables. ie:

```
    private void Calculate()
    {
        /* Use TryParse instead of Parse */
        
        /*Calculate the days stayed price*/
        var dayCharge = 350;
        var daysStay = decimal.Parse(daySpenttxt.Text);
        var stayCharge = dayCharge * daysStay;
// ...
```